# Carbon returns different dateTime when parsing

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a date string and start time as a string too, im first combining the dates with PHP `date()` object, then im parsing to a Carbon object, when I return the carbon object I get a different dateTime than the expected result, for example `$combinedDt = 2021-09-28 19:33` when I return `$parsed` I got `2021-09-29T00:33:00.000000Z"` which is different than the input date

```
        $combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime("$request->date $request->start_time"));
        $parsed = new Carbon($combinedDT, 'America/Bogota');

        return $parsed;
```

How can I fix this problem.

Comment: Check the default application timezone in `config/app.php`

Comment: everything is correct. in the first, you get the exact date with carbon for your location.

And in the second, you get the UTC-0 date, where it mixes up by the hour. If you bring them to the same time zone, then they are the same

Answer (score 1):

you can try this instead of creating 2 different date objects

```
$parsed = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $request->date.' '.$request->start_time));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its natural as you are using two different timezone. You can make it same timezone inside config though or use this.

```
  $parsed= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $request->date)
                        ->setTimezone('America/Bogota');

  return $parsed;
```